# Python 3 input and if statement

Tags: validation, if-statement, python-3.x, user-input

I am having some trouble with an input question that is supposed to allow the player to choose one of 5 starting races. I used the following code.

```
def racechoice():
    players.race = input('After you get a chance to think, you choose to be...') #Here race is chosen
    if players.race == "dwarf" or "Dwarf": #Race starting stats
        players.race = "Dwarf"
        players.level = 1
        players.strength = 12
        players.agility = 6
        players.inteligence = 8
        players.vitality = 14
    elif players.race == "Orc" or "orc":
        players.race = "Orc"
        players.level = 1
        players.strength = 14
        players.agility = 10
        players.inteligence = 4
        players.vitality = 12
    elif players.race == "elf" or "Elf":
        players.level = 1
        players.race = "Elf"
        players.strength = 8
        players.agility = 13
        players.inteligence = 12
        players.vitality = 7
    elif players.race == "Human" or "human":
        players.level = 1
        players.race = "Human"
        players.strength = 10
        players.agility = 10
        players.inteligence = 10
        players.vitality = 10
    elif players.race == "gnome" or "Gnome":
        players.race = "Gnome"
        players.strength = 5
        players.agility = 11
        players.intelligence = 17
        players.vitality = 7
```

When called to display the player's stats:

```
def stats():
    print(players.name)
    print(players.race)
    print("Level: "+ str(players.level) +" Strength: "+ str(players.strength) +" Agility: " + str(players.agility) +" Inteligence: "+ str(players.inteligence) +" Vitality: "+ str(players.vitality))
```

It comes back as Dwarf with Dwarf stats no matter what the player chooses. I'm new-ish to Python and was wondering, did I not use the if/elif statement(s) correctly?
ex) After you get a chance to think, you choose to be...Orc
Ecep
Dwarf
Level: 1 Strength: 12 Agility: 6 Inteligence: 8 Vitality: 14

Comment: Really this has to do with understanding how to handle user input with a list of valid options.  The game is merely the context you are working in, but it is the concept that you need to understand.

Comment: If you are going to use tags, please look at the tags available, and read what they mean on this site, which is for professional and "enthusiast" programmers.  RPG is one of the most widely used languages among professional programmers, running core business applications behind the scenes at more companies than most people realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem, you should do:

```
if players.race == "dwarf" or "players.race == Dwarf":
```

But even better, change your conditions to:

```
elif players.race.lower() == "orc":
```

It is also recommended that you use a class to encapsulate functionality, for example:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, race, level, strength, agility, inteligence, vitality):
        self.race = race
        self.level = level
        self.strength = strength
        self.agility = agility
        self.inteligence = inteligence
        self.vitality = vitality

player = Player('Dwarf', 1, 12, 6, 8, 14)
```

then your `racechoice` function will look so:

```
def racechoice():
    race = input('After you get a chance to think, you choose to be...')
    if race.lower() == 'dwarf':
        player = Player('Dwarf', 1, 12, 6, 8, 14)
    elif race.lower() == 'orc':
        player = Player('Orc', 1, 14, 10, 4, 12)
    ...
    return player
```

Comment: I changed it however am obtaining the same output. Still getting the Dwarf race and stats.

Comment: How do you call the function `racechoice`?

Comment: I called it using racechoice()

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, with the return player what will that do exactly?

Comment: @IanMoon, this allows you to call the function like this in your main code: `player = racechoice()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `or` in that way.  All your `if/elif` statements should be of the form:

```
if players.race == "dwarf" or players.race == "Dwarf":
```

`"Dwarf"` all by itself is considered `True` by Python and empty strings `""` are considered `False`, so your first `if` always succeeds.

Comment: That worked, and got the proper output. After you get a chance to think, you choose to be...Orc
Ecep
Orc
Level: 1 Strength: 14 Agility: 10 Inteligence: 4 Vitality: 12